# Find the Maximum from a Count in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, count, group-by

I've a database of musical tracks, and I'm trying to find which genre has the most tracks. Genre is stored in a Work table, with each track in the Track table having a field for which Work it belongs to.

This query correctly returns the genres and how many tracks they each have:

```
SELECT w.genre
     , COUNT(t.name) [numTracks] 
  FROM Track t
  LEFT 
  JOIN Work w 
    ON t.workName = w.name 
  LEFT 
  JOIN AlbumContains ta
    ON ta.workName = t.workName  
 GROUP 
    BY w.genre
```

But I can't find a way to just take whichever genre (or multiple genres) has the highest numTracks from that result.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: mysql, sql mentioned in tags @Strawberry

Comment: @Strawberry It's MS SQL Server, I'm not sure how that tag got added.

Comment: I believe M$SQL uses TOP but not using it, I don't really know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

**MySQL**

```
SELECT w.genre, COUNT(t.name) AS numTracks
FROM work w 
LEFT JOIN Track t ON t.workName = w.name 
GROUP BY w.genre
ORDER BY COUNT(t.name) DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

**SQL SERVER**

```
SELECT TOP 1 w.genre, COUNT(t.name) AS numTracks
FROM work w 
LEFT JOIN Track t ON t.workName = w.name 
GROUP BY w.genre
ORDER BY COUNT(t.name) DESC
```

Comment: That's just returning the list of genres and how many tracks are in each

Comment: I'm trying to find which genre (or genres) has the most tracks

Comment: I get an "Incorrect syntax near 'LIMIT'." error with that. And would that return all the genres with the most tracks, or just the top one?

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from (SELECT Work.genre, count(Track.name) as numTracks FROM Track LEFT JOIN Work ON Track.workName=Work.name LEFT JOIN AlbumContains ON Track.workName=AlbumContains.workName GROUP BY Work.genre)alias order by aias. numTracks desc limit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is not exactly, but somehow similar to this problem:
[SQL Select only rows with Max Value on a Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column)

If you want to have all genres with the most tracks and not only one (as far as I understand, you want that in your question), then you might have to join your query again, or maybe use a subselect like this (MySQL):

```
SELECT Work.genre, count(Track.name) as numTracks
  FROM Track
  LEFT JOIN Work ON Track.workName=Work.name
  GROUP BY Work.genre
  HAVING numTracks=
  (SELECT count(Track.name) as numTracks
    FROM Track
    LEFT JOIN Work ON Track.workName=Work.name
    GROUP BY Work.genre
    ORDER BY numTracks DESC
    LIMIT 1);
```

Or this in MS SQL:

```
SELECT Work.genre, count(Track.name) as numTracks
  FROM Track
  LEFT JOIN Work ON Track.workName=Work.name
  GROUP BY Work.genre
  HAVING count(Track.name) =
  (SELECT TOP(1) count(Track.name) as numTracks2
    FROM Track
    LEFT JOIN Work ON Track.workName=Work.name
    GROUP BY Work.genre
    ORDER BY numTracks2 DESC
  );
```

This looks rather awkward, but probably the server optimizes the subquery. However, for a solution with better performance, you may consider using a cursor instead.